# Else If textfield (Android)

Tags: java, android, text, field

I am creating a else if statement for a textfield i have on my view, i am using this code right now. But i'm running into a few errors

```
private EditText editText;

editText = findViewById(R.id.your_custom_id);

//then something like this

Sting text = editText.getText();

if(text.equals("foo") {
   // do something
else if(text.equals("bar") {
  // do something else
} else {
  // something else
}
```

The errors consist of "Can't resolve symbol for 'sting' or 'equals'. 'Unknown class "editText" in the 'editText = findViewbyid...'. And the last one is 'Else without if' on the "else if(text.equals("bar")" code. How can i resolve this?

Comment: where did you get this code?

Comment: your `if` block is not closed.

Answer (score 2):

See `Sting text = editText.getText();` This is totally incorrect.
There is no such thing as Sting it's **String**.Equal method apply on object types and **String** is an Object.

Also you need to use **toString()**.
Use `String text = editText.getText().toString();`

you need to use `editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_custom_id);`

instead of `editText = findViewById(R.id.your_custom_id);`.

Comment: So what about the other errors.  like 'unknown class editText',  'Can't resolve symbol 'equals'.  and 'else with out if' error.